# Choice between interpolation search and binary search

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search, heuristics

I have a static sorted integer array of size N.
There will be a lot of element search queries
(get index of an element if it exists or of the nearest lesser element if it doesn't),
and I have to choose whether to use interpolation search or to stay with old good binary search.

- how large is N when there is significant benefit from interpolation search?
- what test to use for a check that the array values are uniformly distributed?
- are there any other heuristics that can help me with the choice?

Comment: Is your array sorted? Is there a reason not to put the array members in set for O(1) lookup?

Comment: @Dave I clarified the question

Comment: Interpolation lookup wins if the data in the table is roughly uniformly distributed. If the data has notable hotspots or is distributed exponentially, then interpolation lookup can result in much slower lookups, not necessarily even O(log N). So use it with care.